# React Native Maps-based parsing error keeps coming up when trying to end the code

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to code an iOS app, exporting it to Expo to use as an emulator. Apparently when trying to end the "render" function I get a parsing error. I also am getting a "constructor expected" error when I try to put under super.

I've tried ripping it apart, adding more middle-brackets to the end, changing up where a component goes. Nothing seems to work. Not sure if this is an Expo problem or if I just have bad code. I still need to add a Marker or two to this.. feels like it will take forever.

Code:

```
class App extends Component,
 constructor(props){

 this.state = {
    position: null
 };
}; 


componentDidMount(); {
 this._getCoords();
};


_getCoords = () => {

 alert=("_getCoords")

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(

  (position) => {

   var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position.coords);

   this.setState({position: initialPosition});

   let tempCoords = {
            latitude: Number(position.coords.latitude),
            longitude: Number(position.coords.longitude)
    }

        this._map.animateToCoordinate(tempCoords, 1);

  }, function (error) { alert(error) },

 );
};

render(); {
 return (
    <MapView
     style= {style.map}
     initialRegion={{
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
     }}
    />
);`
```

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Edited appropriately, sorry. Using dark mode didn't lend itself to seeing how I needed to put in my code.

Comment: `class App extends Component,`. where is the open brace for Component???
Is that missing while copying or if not can you please share full code of `App.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors, the correct syntax should be like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      position: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._getCoords()
  }

  _getCoords = () => {
    alert = '_getCoords'

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position.coords)

        this.setState({ position: initialPosition })

        let tempCoords = {
          latitude: Number(position.coords.latitude),
          longitude: Number(position.coords.longitude)
        }
        this._map.animateToCoordinate(tempCoords, 1)
      },
      function(error) {
        alert(error)
      }
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MapView
        style={style.map}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}
```